# Unable to add images using carrierwave in Devise resistration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an institute model which has picture attribute. I am using carrierwave to upload images.

```
class Institute < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

PictureUploader for carrierwave

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]
  storage :file
end
```

devise form for uploading image

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put ,  multipart: true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture,accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
<% end %>
```

migration

```
add_column :institutes, :picture, :string
```

Strong parameters are handled in application controller with

```
  class Institute::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    def sign_up
      default_params.permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:picture)
    end
  end
```

But when I save it the picture is not being saved. I have no idea where it is going wrong. The picture attribute is getting saved. but

```
institute.picture.url => nil
```

I have spent a long time n this but cant figure out why this is happening. Is there a way to debug? Expecting some solutions. Thanks..

```
Started PUT "/institutes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-25 00:06:27 +0530
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EoILK8UjrjjLfyxnFu6ozlqmfHDb/D9fp7CTmLHEjjr5i9h9ZaHGrkG4e5WUhVHMc/jirgu7+vSyH+bRrqWRAg==", "institute"=>{"email"=>"raj@gmail.com", "name"=>"RajeevIn", "phone_no"=>"555555", "address"=>"", "description"=>"", "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003e34178 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151025-28776-o2ywzl.jpg>, @original_filename="12redroses_silk.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"institute[picture]\"; filename=\"12redroses_silk.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  Institute Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "institutes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Institute Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: name, phone_no, address, description, picture
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
```

the `institute.picture?` method provided by carrierwave gives `false` is false even when the `institue.picture` exists.

Comment: some logs of rails please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are performing the update action but are whitelisting for signup. 
so change ParameterSanitizer class to this:

```
 class Institute::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    def sign_up
      default_params.permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:picture)
    end

   def account_update
    default_params.permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:picture)
   end
  end
```

you can add this(if not already done)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == Institute
      Institute::ParameterSanitizer.new(Institute, :institute, params)
    else
      super # Use the default one
    end
  end
end
```

After this this line `Unpermitted parameters: name, phone_no, address, description, picture` should not appear in logs. if it still appear then that means the params whitelisting is not taken effect. In which case please share a sample app which reproduces this issue on github, I will help you fix it.

Comment: That was the one.Thanks man. but why was institute.picture not nil?

Comment: That's how the API works. `institute.picture` is carrierwave method.so it doesn't behave like other AR attributes. Hence, it will never be `nil`.you have to use methods given by carreriwave to check if picture was nil or not. for example `picture.file.exists?` should be false if image doesn't exist. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Havnt reached 15 reputation. Otherwise would have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to check it:

- make sure you use save! to so that it throws an exception if it is not being saved.

Comment: how do i make sure carrierwave is loaded after ORM ?

Comment: is the file being saved? Try checking the database to see if the file exists there after save!

Comment: the file is not saves in the databse right? The path shown in PictureUploader.rb doesnt exist in the app directory.